# Change Locale of Excel Interop

Tags: c#, excel, automation, office-interop, excel-interop

I am trying to automate Excel to save Excel files to PDF but I need to change the locale of am Excel file at runtime to **meet Number and Date format** requirements.

So far what I tried is to set Thread locale in which Interop is executed but that doesn't work: no changes in the Excel file, the locale is still that of the Windows OS.

I need to change locale at runtime. I am building an Excel to pdf converter for my company to allow workers to submit their Excel files. The Windows on which the converter would be installed is set to default US English locale. The problem is, some Excel files are created in non-US English locales where Number and Date formats should be persisted. For example, I have an Excel file created using a Lithuanian locale with a date format like 2019-01-23. If the file would be submitted to the converter on a system with a US English locale the date would be changed to 01/23/19 in the PDF file.

I have the idea to allow workers to submit an Excel file along with the Locale to persist dates and numbers format.

The only problem left to solve is how to change Excel Interop locale dynamically?

```
        var theNewThread = new Thread(() =>
        {                
            Excel(@"C:\Projects\TestFiles\test-locale.xlsx", @"C:\Projects\_temp\excel.pdf");                
        });
        theNewThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("pt-BR");
        theNewThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("pt-BR");
        theNewThread.Start();

              private static void Excel(string inFilePath, string outFilePath)
        {           

            var application = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();

            application.AutomationSecurity = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoAutomationSecurity.msoAutomationSecurityForceDisable;

            var workbook = application.Workbooks.Open(inFilePath, ReadOnly: Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoTrue);


            try
            {
                workbook.ExportAsFixedFormat(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFixedFormatType.xlTypePDF, outFilePath);
            }
            finally
            {
                if (workbook != null)
                {
                    workbook.Close();
                }

                application.Quit();
            }
        }
```

Comment: I have a bad feeling you're automating Excel from somewhere you really shouldn't - such as from inside a web application or windows service?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I am running the demo from c# windows console app.

Comment: This can't be done by changing the Culture of the thread over which the software is communicating with Excel. Either the Windows settings need to be changed or the information in the Excel file. I'm not an Excel specialist so I'm not sure what the optimum approach is. Certainly, it would be possible to change the number and date settings in Windows for the duration of the conversion. It might also be possible to apply custom number and date formats to the cell content... Another possible approach would be to identify such content and convert it to static string content in the correct format?

Comment: It would probably be a good idea to research / ask in an Excel venue. There are a number of web-sites and forums that specialize in Excel. Here on SO you might try asking with the vba and excel tags...